# CDS basis trade using Risk free rate

Tags: cds, repo-rate

The CDS spread pricing model uses “**Risk free rate**” to discount the PV and the Z-spread also uses “**Risk free rate**” to compute the spread. But the given example uses repo rate that comparing to Libor:

For “Negative Basis Trade”

- Z spread = 100 bps
- CDS spread = 40 bps
- Repo rate = 2% or Libor plus 20 bps

Thus, long the bond to receive at 100bps and borrow from repo at 2% or Libor plus 20 bps and buy CDS protection at 40 bps.

$$100 - (40+20) = 40bps$$

Q: Why does this example use the spread over Libor instead of the spread over “**Risk free rate**” (SOFR, Secured Overnight Financing Rate) in order to be consistent?

Comment: This example (where did you find it?) is probably old and came before the use of SOFR.

Comment: @noob2 I found on this paper “Trading the CDS basis by Moorad Choudhry”. But on his paper, he uses ASW spread instead of Z-spread. But it’s got me thinking tht CDS pricing model still uses a risk free rate anyway.

Comment: https://jot.pm-research.com/content/2/1/79 2007 paper before SOFR , before LIBOR scandal.

Comment: @DimitriVulis So, does this mean everyone now uses SOFR?

Comment: We’re looking at the spread $\Delta$ for CDS basis trade, right? Whether Libor or Risk free rate, why don’t we apply one or another across all the variables in the equation?

Comment: As of March 2020, no, we're still pretty far from everyone using SOFR.

Comment: @DimitriVulis I appreciate for your input Sir. 